# Select rows in a data frame based on the date range

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
mylist=
[{'Date': '10/2/2021', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': 'Mike'},
{'Date': '10/2/2021', 'ID': 15673, 'Receiver': 'Jane'},
{'Date': '10/3/2021', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': 'Mike'},
... 
{'Date': '12/25/2021', 'ID': 34653, 'Receiver': 'Jack'}]
```

I want to select the rows within a date range, for example from 10/3/2021 to 11/3/2021. I tried the following steps:

```
dfmylist = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
dfmylistnew = (dfmylist['Date'] > '10/3/2021') & (dfmylist['Date'] <= '11/3/2021')
```

I converted my list to a data frame and then select the date range. However, the `dfmylistnew` data frame doesn't show up properly. What did I miss?

The output of `dfmylistnew` is:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't show up properly?

Comment: You can put the output `dfmylistnew` in your question please

Comment: You can try my example, it worked very well with me. I do not know the data you have. You should check your condition and the data between these two dates.

Comment: Based on your condition, only the rows dated in 11/03/2021 will appear.  Do you have some rows dated in 11/03/2021?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, I have more rows. The post here only lists a few examples. Thank you so much for the help  ;)

Comment: You are so welecome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You missed to convert the "Date" to datetime type:*

```
import pandas as pd

mylist=[{'Date': '10/2/2021', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': 'Mike'},
{'Date': '10/2/2021', 'ID': 15673, 'Receiver': 'Jane'},
{'Date': '10/3/2021', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': 'Mike'},
{'Date': '12/25/2021', 'ID': 34653, 'Receiver': 'Jack'}]

dfmylist = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

dfmylist['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfmylist['Date']) # you missed this line

dfmylistnew = (dfmylist['Date'] > '10/2/2021') & (dfmylist['Date'] <= '11/3/2021')

dfmylist.loc[dfmylistnew]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to change the Date column to the index of the Dataframe, once that is set to the index python will recognize it as a date field and you can use a df.loc to find the data between specified dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.set_index('Date')
df.loc['10/3/2021':'11/3/2021']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dfmylistnew = dfmylist[list(dfmylist['Date'] > '10/3/2021') and list(dfmylist['Date']<='11/3/2021')]
```